# mysql sum after group by

Tags: php, mysql

Cart table:

```
itemid | amount 
------ | ------
1      | 2
2      | 4
```

Products table:

```
itemid | Price
------ | ------
1      | 10
2      | 20
```

What I have tried so far:

```
$cartPrice = 
"SELECT (SUM(products.Price) * SUM(cart.amount)) 
AS total_price 
FROM cart 
INNER JOIN products 
ON cart.itemid = products.itemid 
WHERE userid = '$IP' 
GROUP BY cart.itemid";

$Price = $mysqli->query($cartPrice);
$rowPrice = $Price->fetch_assoc();

echo "Total: ". $rowPrice['total_price'] ." ";
```

My MYSQL Query outputs the following:

```
total_price |
----------- | 
20          | 
80          |
```

It will echo the last result. But I need the total of 80 + 20. How do I do this?

Result I get at the moment:

```
Total: 80
```

Result I want:

```
Total: 100
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to `GROUP BY` since you want only one row returned:

```sql
SELECT SUM(products.Price* cart.amount) AS total_price 
FROM cart 
INNER JOIN products 
ON cart.itemid = products.itemid 
WHERE userid = '$IP'
```

Comment: You're quick, thanks for the solution! This worked out for me.

Comment: @Niels Glad I was able to help and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please mark this, or any other, answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can `SUM` the result of a subquery, like this:

```
SELECT SUM(total_price) as total_price FROM
(
    SELECT (SUM(products.Price) * SUM(cart.amount))  AS total_price 
    FROM cart 
    INNER JOIN products 
    ON cart.itemid = products.itemid 
    WHERE userid = '$IP' 
    GROUP BY cart.itemid
) total_prices
```

Comment: You're quick, thanks for the solution! This worked out for me.

Comment: No problem. Look at @GiorgosBetsos solution, it should be better in your case.

Comment: Yes, but his solution will run faster. But keep in mind that you can summarize subselects.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is the use of an union   with a second select without the group  by

```
" SELECT (SUM(products.Price) * SUM(cart.amount))  AS total_price 
  FROM cart 
  INNER JOIN products 
  ON cart.itemid = products.itemid 
  WHERE userid = '$IP' 
  GROUP BY cart.itemid
  UNION 
  SELECT (SUM(products.Price) * SUM(cart.amount))  
  FROM cart 
  INNER JOIN products 
  ON cart.itemid = products.itemid 
  WHERE userid = '$IP' ";
```

the firts select return the main rows  and the second the final total

Comment: although I got the same result with your method I still want to thank you for your help. Giorgos Betsos had the solution.